Table fields are masked even when tag is dropped
Masking when reapplied works fine on new data, but old data is always masked. Looks like the data itself is permanently lost. What could have caused this and are there any solutions?

Please update your question with details (e.g. DDL statements for the masking policies, tags, tables/views being masked, etc) showing how you are masking your data. Also show the query you are running and the output you are getting

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
